# Is terse chaining assignment operators in javascript safe? (to nullify variables)

Tags: javascript

If I want to tersely nullfiy some variables:

```
var a = 'testa';
var b = 'testb';
var c = 'testc';
```

with:

```
a = b = c = null;
```

Is it safe?

**EDIT** removed superfluous `var` keyword

Comment: Yes...  what might not be safe or what do you think could go wrong? Please elaborate on your source of confusion; I don't really know how to explain that this is "safe" when I'm not sure what could go wrong.

Comment: You probably shouldn't have a `var` in the compound assignment because it creates the mistaken impression that you are redeclaring `a`.

Comment: @Baconbeastnz seperate `var` and assignment operation: `var a,b,c; a=b=c="test";`

Comment: Thanks guys, yip that var was a typo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var a = b = c = null;` is evaluated as `var a = (b = (c = null));` because JavaScript does **right-to-left** evaluation. Since `c` and `b` are not defined, `c` and `b` will become global variables while `a` is local since `a` is defined with `var`.

So it is safer to do

```
var a, b, c;
a = b = c = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

[It's not safe, it's... very dangerous, be careful.](http://www.foinews.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/01/marathon-man-olivier_l.jpg)

I tried this from the command line:

```
var f = function() { var a = b = c = null; }
f()
console.log(c)
console.log(b)
console.log(a)
```

And got this

> null
>   null
>   ReferenceError: a is not defined

So `b` and `c` were *global* variables!  The `var` was ignored!  Eek!

Comment: It doesn't seem correct since `a` is defined in the function.

Comment: It wasn't ignored, it just applies to a.

Comment: @sza -- do you think the computer got it wrong?  The question is, *since* `a` is defined in the function, why isn't it defined when I go to log it?  And the answer is, the entire point of the `var` statement is to define a variable as **local** to the current function.

Comment: @bfavaretto -- yes, it wasn't *totally* ignored, but ignored enough to screw up the OP.

Comment: @Malvolio I didn't down vote :) In your example,`a` is local and `b`, `c` are global, this is absolutely correct. But in the question, all 3 variables are declared using var, so they are all local to the current scope.

Comment: @Musa -- sorry, cut-and-paste error (fixed now).  I was logging `a`.  But the **error** was reproduced in your fiddle.  Those `b` and `c` variables should have been undefined, and were instead null.  Very bad.

Comment: @sza -- the OP is asking whether the two versions are identical.  They very very are not.  His first version declares them as local; the second does not.  (I may have misread question: he may be planning to use all four lines, in which case the last `var` is superfluous and arguably erroneous, but not dangerous.)

Comment: The error occurred because a was out of scope (it was defined local to the function) and b and c set to null so why should they be undefined?

Comment: @Musa -- I don't think that the OP intended to declare b and c as global variables.  (Maybe I'm misreading him, but I don't think he intended a to be special.)

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. They are all just in the scope they r in -=). The extra var, was a mistake.

Comment: Edited.  If the variables are declared properly elsewhere, the chained assignment is fine.